# cURL Empty JPEG Downloaded

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I have a function that gets an image from a provided URL e.g. to download a user's image to an images folder for further reference. Below is the function:

```
public function _get_image_from_url($url)
{
    $image_name = $this->uuid->v4().'.jpg';
    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image_name, '.'), 1));
    $path = APPPATH.'../assets/uploads/images/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen($path.$image_name, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    switch( $file_extension ) {
        case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
        case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
        default:
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Content-type: '.$ctype,
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    return $image_name;
}
```

Note: I am using CI 3 and the uuid library to generate the file name, which is saved to the database. I have confirmed curl is enabled on remote server and file permissions are good.

Problem: The function works on the local machine (Linux) but when executed on a remote server (shared hosting), the saved file is empty (and for some reason, the file type is 'jpeg-file')

Any help on solving why the executing on the remote server fails to correctly download an image will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you setting the header with the content type?

Comment: Have you tried `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` for both fetching the URL and writing in locally?

Comment: Check if you don't have anything suspicious in `~/.curlrc`.

Comment: @fvu, I quite new to cURL. I thought the issue of the remote server downloading a jpeg-file was a header issue. Your thoughts are welcomed..

Comment: @mike.k, file_get_contents() failed on remote. Read somewhere that it may be disabled and cURL was the other alternative. Was using http://tutsnare.com/getting-image-from-url-php-using-curl-or-fopen/

Comment: @kenorb, is that on the remote server? It is shared hosting, so quite limited.

Comment: @NdiranguWaweru Then try executing in PHP something like: `system('curl -v http://example.com/');`. If that works, then you may change URL to point to your image, to check for any visible curl errors. If you've any errors, please post them.

Comment: See: [curl_exec not returning data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8410106/55075)

Comment: @kenorb, works fine on local machine, shows blank page on remote server. No error logs generated either.

Comment: @NdiranguWaweru Blank doesn't help much. You've to activate the error logging first. Add this before your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Make sure you haven't done any syntax error.

Comment: @kenorb, appologies for that. amateur move. The error on the page on the remote side is: system() has been disabled for security reasons.

Comment: Do you have access to `wget` and `exec()` on that system? Perhaps not if `system()` is disabled, but worth a shot.

Comment: @NdiranguWaweru So if you're seeing now the errors, try the curl code and check what's the error then printing via `curl_error()` as described in linked post before.

Comment: @NdiranguWaweru Or try some alternative solutions such as `file_get_contents($url)` or `fsockopen()`.