# Bittrex API request

Tags: php, html, json

I'm trying to get my wallet balance with the bittrex API and I don't understand why the code provided by bittrex documentation doesn't work:

```
$apikey = 'xxx';
$apisecret = 'xxx';
$nonce = time();
$uri = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=' .
    $apikey . '&nonce=' . $nonce;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $uri, $apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:' . $sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

The `curl_exec` function returns false, I don't understand why.

Comment: You should check for errors, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410106/curl-exec-not-returning-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl\_exec not returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410106/curl-exec-not-returning-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add further error handling,
smthing like this

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);

    if (FALSE === $execResult)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

}
```

Comment: I've got this error : Fatal error: Curl failed with error #60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: [Look @ this question for further information about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: execute your code on live website or IP. As i have experienced this will not work in your local system.